# Kernel Upgrade with grsecurity - Debian

Tags: debian, kernel

I would like to upgrade kernel on my server from version 2.6.32 to the newest with Grsecurity. But after restarting the server there is still old version of kernel, can you tell me what I have done wrong.

I will just briefly explain what I done, so I install all needed patches for example gcc, build-essential etc. then I get a new kernel file from kernel.org, I unpack it, and I patch it with grsecurity (using patch -p1 <../grsecurity-[version of grsecurity] command), than I type make defconfig and make menuconfig, in configuration I only enabled grsecurity in automatic mode, than I save config file and I type make deb-pkg, after whole process I use dpkg -i *.deb to active new image and when I did reboot, the old image was still running on the server.

Whole compilation process was fine, there was just few warnings and notes, but in the end the image was build in the file.

And ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your grub configuration has been updated.

```
update-grub2
```

Then check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Still doesn't work... I did update-drub2 than I get this Found linux image: /boot/bzImage-3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.57-grsec
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.57-grsec
  No volume groups found
done